# How to load cell array of strings in Matlab mat files into Python list or tuple using Scipy.io.loadmat

Tags: python, arrays, string, matlab, mat-file

I am a Matlab user new to Python. I would like to write a cell array of strings in Matlab to a Mat file, and load this Mat file using Python (maybe scipy.io.loadmat) into some similar type (e.g list of strings or tuple of strings). But loadmat read things into array and I am not sure how to convert it into a list. I tried the "tolist" function which does not work as I expected ( I have a poor understanding of Python array or numpy array). For example:

Matlab code:

```
cell_of_strings = {'thank',  'you', 'very', 'much'};
save('my.mat', 'cell_of_strings');
```

Python code:

```
matdata=loadmat('my.mat', chars_as_strings=1, matlab_compatible=1);
array_of_strings = matdata['cell_of_strings']
```

Then, the variable array_of_strings is:

```
array([[[[u't' u'h' u'a' u'n' u'k']], [[u'y' u'o' u'u']],
    [[u'v' u'e' u'r' u'y']], [[u'm' u'u' u'c' u'h']]]], dtype=object)
```

I am not sure how to convert this array_of_strings into a Python list or tuple so that it looks like

```
list_of_strings = ['thank',  'you', 'very', 'much'];
```

I am not familiar with the array object in Python or numpy. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Have your tried this:

```
import scipy.io as si

a = si.loadmat('my.mat')
b = a['cell_of_strings']                # type(b) <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
list_of_strings  = b.tolist()           # type(list_of_strings ) <type 'list'>

print list_of_strings 
# output: [u'thank', u'you', u'very', u'much']
```

Comment: b.tolist() gives [[array([[u't', u'h', u'a', u'n', u'k']], 
      dtype='<U1'),
  array([[u'y', u'o', u'u']], 
      dtype='<U1'),
  array([[u'v', u'e', u'r', u'y']], 
      dtype='<U1'),
  array([[u'm', u'u', u'c', u'h']], 
      dtype='<U1')]], which seems still an array

Comment: @Denzel. Do you must use chars_as_strings=1, matlab_compatible=1?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a job for [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Repeating your example, I did this in MATLAB:

```
cell_of_strings = {'thank',  'you', 'very', 'much'};
save('my.mat', 'cell_of_strings','-v7');
```

I'm using a newer version of MATLAB, which saves `.mat` files in HDF5 format by default. `loadmat` can't read HDF5 files, so the '-v7' flag is to force MATLAB  to save to an older version `.mat` file, which `loadmat` can understand.

In Python, I loaded the cell array just like you did:

```
import scipy.io as sio
matdata = sio.loadmat('%s/my.mat' %path, chars_as_strings=1, matlab_compatible=1);  
array_of_strings = matdata['cell_of_strings']
```

Printing `array_of_strings` gives:

```
[[array([[u't', u'h', u'a', u'n', u'k']], 
          dtype='<U1')
      array([[u'y', u'o', u'u']], 
          dtype='<U1')
      array([[u'v', u'e', u'r', u'y']], 
          dtype='<U1')
      array([[u'm', u'u', u'c', u'h']], 
          dtype='<U1')]]
```

The variable `array_of_strings` is a (1,4) numpy object array but there are arrays nested within each object. For example, the first element of `array_of_strings` is an (1,5) array containing the letters for 'thank'. That is,

```
array_of_strings[0,0]
array([[u't', u'h', u'a', u'n', u'k']], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

To get at the first letter 't', you have to do something like:

```
array_of_strings[0,0][0,0]
u't'
```

Since we are dealing with nested arrays, we need to employ some recursive technique to extract the data, i.e. nested `for` loops. But first, I'll show you how to extract the first word:

```
first_word = [str(''.join(letter)) for letter in array_of_strings[0][0]]
first_word
['thank']
```

Here I am using a list comprehension. Basically, I am looping through each letter in array_of_strings[0][0] and concatenating them using the `''.join` method. The `string()` function is to convert the unicode strings into regular strings.

Now, to get the list strings you want, we just need to loop through each array of letters:

```
words = [str(''.join(letter)) for letter_array in array_of_strings[0] for letter in letter_array]
words
['thank', 'you', 'very', 'much']
```

List comprehensions take some getting used to, but they are extremely useful. Hope this helps.

Comment: words = [str(''.join(letter)) for letter_array in array_of_strings[0] for letter in letter_array] should be  words = [str(''.join(letter)) for letter_array in array_of_strings for letter in letter_array]